# What does "null" mean when passed as the provider to DateTime.TryParseExact?

Tags: c#, datetime

In the following code:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(Date, "MM/dd/yyyy", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out Test)
```

What does this `null` keyword signify?

Comment: Null means null! Now seriously, have you checked the documentation in MSDN?

Comment: As written in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx): If provider is null, the CultureInfo object that corresponds to the current culture is used.

Comment: Please take time to refine/focus a question - be specific! I've edited it a good bit to add such focus, but it should be easy to find such answers when starting from such a base.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you provide `null` as third parameter for `DateTime.TryParseExact` that means that [`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx) will be used.

[**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx):

> If provider is null, the CultureInfo object that corresponds to the
>   current culture is used.

Answer (score 5):

By passing null here, it is the same as passing `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`.

You could instead pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, or pass a specific culture such as `CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")`.

Answer (score 4):

This is covered in the documentation for [DateTime.TryParseExact Method (String, String, IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles, DateTime)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx):

> If provider is null, the CultureInfo object that corresponds to the current culture is used.

Answer (score 2):

You're setting the IFormatProvider to null. This means that CultureInfo.CurrentCulture will be used